# Postgresql Issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to do a join with a LEFT(column,5) but I am not getting the syntax right.  Of the code below how should I be accomplishing this?  I'm usually doing MSSQL so I'm not sure if the syntax is different or I'm just doing something wrong.

```
select * from ofbiz.supplier_product a
join ofbiz.supplier_product b on a.(LEFT(prod_catalog_id,5)) = b.party_id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from ofbiz.supplier_product a
join ofbiz.supplier_product b on LEFT(a.prod_catalog_id,5) = b.party_id
```

Comment: Thanks!  It would have been better if I had both my tables in there and not just one XD